# How to have gap between the frame and a component?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jlabel, layout-manager

I'm trying practice my GUI and I am having troubles putting gap between component and the frame. 
[image]

The picture above is what I have so far. But I really want to put a gap between the left side of the frame and "label1".

```
private void initialize() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("WINDOW");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 300);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    bottomPanel = new JPanel();
    bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5));
    l1 = new JLabel("Label1");
    l2 = new JLabel("Label2");
    l3 = new JLabel("Label3");
    l4 = new JLabel("Label4");
    l5 = new JLabel("Label5");
    bottomPanel.add(l1);
    bottomPanel.add(l2);
    bottomPanel.add(l3);
    bottomPanel.add(l4);
    bottomPanel.add(l5);

    panel.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(panel);
}
```

Above is part my code. I tried doing:
       bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 5, -20, 0));
to put some horizontal gap but that only added gap between the components. That didn't move "label1" away from the frame at all. Is there any other way of doing this? I am very new to Java so I don't really know much of the other tricks. I would appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are fudges that won't achieve the desired effect when the GUI is resized. Instead use:

```
JLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
```

By centering the text within the `JLabel`, combined with `GridLayout` stretching the components to the full width of the cell, each label will have as much space either side as the GUI can allow. E.G. here is the effect when the GUI is at minimum size.

[image]

And when stretched wider:

[image]

(The red border is added to show the bounds of each label.)

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Border` to the panel:

```
bottomPanel = new JPanel();
bottomPanel.setBorder( new EmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 0) );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information about the different borders you can create.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
bottomPanel.add(javax.swing.Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));

Comment: Creating a Swing component uses more resources than just painting a Border. Also, it would not work since the panel is using a GridLayout so you can't control the size of the empty space since it will automatically be the same size as the other components in the grid.